# react router dom v6 useNavigate not working with nested routes

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm trying to use useNavigate in one of my components but nothing happens and I have no errors. 
I have a menu with subMenu so I got an error (nested a) because I have a Link in a Link. 
So I'm trying to remove one Link and replace it with a navigate but with no success so far. 
I'm not used to react router (i worked on Nextjs projects before).

My routing :

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/reset-password" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/renew-password" element={<Main />} />
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<NoPage />} />
            <Route path="/comptes-clients" element={<ClientsAccounts />} />
            <Route path="/comptes-clients/comptes" element={<Accounts />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

And in a sub components (Menu) from the Layout component, on a onClick I tried a navigate("/login") but nothings happens and I have no error. 
I have imported useNavigate from react router. 
What I am missing here ?